# Python URL Comparison

Tags: python, url, comparison

I have two URLS from which I have extracted hostnames using urlparse(). The result is:
   URL1='ads.indiaresults.com' and URL2='haryana.indiaresults.com'

Now how can I check if they are from the same domain or website. I have to make a general method so that it works on all URLS as some time hostnames are like:
    (www.google.com , www.e-tutes.com)

Comment: With `==`? Your URL1 and URL2 are different domains.

Comment: Use `urllib.parse` for bringing them into an equal format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an answer:

Split your URLs :

```
URL1Split = URL1.split(".")
URL2Split = URL2.split(".")
```

Then, reverse the lists:

```
a = URL1Split[::-1]
b = URL2Split[::-1]
```

Now, you just have to pick the 2 firsts items to get the domain name:

```
domain1 = a[1] + "." + a[0]
domain2 = b[1] + "." + b[0]
```

Here's a function if you want :

```
def compDom(URL1,URL2):
  URL1Split = URL1.split(".")
  URL2Split = URL2.split(".")
  a = URL1Split[::-1]
  b = URL2Split[::-1]
  domain1 = a[1] + "." + a[0]
  domain2 = b[1] + "." + b[0]
  if domain1 == domain2:
      return 1
  else:
      return 0
```

Comment: Working till now... I will check on more instances... Thanks